# Issue in getting values from array through foreach loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

```
<?php
$v = array();
$text_attributes = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($input_text as $key => $value):
    $i++;
    $v[$i]=$value;
    $text_attributes[$key] = explode("\t", $v[$i]);
endforeach;
echo "<pre>";
print_r($text_attributes);
die();
?>
```

The result I get from this code is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => text
            [1] => Composition
            [2] => 1text1
            [3] => Test saf af saf
        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => image
        [1] => c://xampp/htdocs/clickcue/application/app/webroot/files/ae_templates/rendered_templates/192/710/
        [2] => i1.jpg
        [3] => Chrysanthemum - Copy - Copy.jpg
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => Composition
        [2] => 2text1
        [3] => Test blkjb
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => Composition
        [2] => 2text2
        [3] => Test  jb
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => Composition
        [2] => 2text3
        [3] => Test kjb
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => image
        [1] => c://xampp/htdocs/clickcue/application/app/webroot/files/ae_templates/rendered_templates/192/710/
        [2] => i2.jpg
        [3] => Desert.jpg
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => image1
        [2] => i1text1
        [3] => Test lkjb
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => image1
        [2] => i1text2
        [3] => Test k
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => image1
        [2] => i1text3
        [3] => Test b
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [0] => image
        [1] => c://xampp/htdocs/clickcue/application/app/webroot/files/ae_templates/rendered_templates/192/710/
        [2] => i3.jpg
        [3] => Hydrangeas - Copy - Copy.jpg
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => image2
        [2] => i2text1
        [3] => Test kj
    )

[11] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => image2
        [2] => i2text2
        [3] => Test b
    )

[12] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => image2
        [2] => i2text3
        [3] => Test kjb
    )

[13] => Array
    (
        [0] => image
        [1] => c://xampp/htdocs/clickcue/application/app/webroot/files/ae_templates/rendered_templates/192/710/
        [2] => i4.jpg
        [3] => Jellyfish - Copy (2).jpg
    )

[14] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => image3
        [2] => i3text1
        [3] => Test b
    )

[15] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => image3
        [2] => i3text2
        [3] => Test kljb
    )

[16] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => image3
        [2] => i3text3
        [3] => Test kj
    )

[17] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => Composition
        [2] => 4text1
        [3] => Test b
    )

[18] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => Composition
        [2] => 4text2
        [3] => Test kj
    )

[19] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => Composition
        [2] => 5text1
        [3] => Test b
    )

[20] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => Composition
        [2] => 5text2
        [3] => Test kjb
    )

[21] => Array
    (
        [0] => text
        [1] => Composition
        [2] => 5text3
        [3] => Test kj
    )
```

)

Now I want to show the result according to the index value of array..
means if 0 index contains text than it will show the value of last index in textbox,and if the first index contains the value of image than it shows the value of image on 2nd index.But this loop always show me the last value of the array.
e,g

```
if($text_attributes[0]=='images')
{
    echo $text_attributes[3];
}
if($text_attributes[0]=='text')
{
    echo $text_attributes[2];
}
```

Kindly some one get me out of this problem.. 
Thanks in Advanced

Comment: `$text_attributes[0]` -> `$text_attributes[0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

inside your foreach loop after $text_attributes[$key] = explode("\t", $v[$i]); line. try this

```
if($text_attributes[$key][0]=='images')
{
    echo $text_attributes[$key][3];

}
if($text_attributes[$key][0]=='text')
{
    echo $text_attributes[$key][2];
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but it shows the last value of the array only.

Answer (score 0):

I write a code from your result try this hope this will help you.

```
$textAttributes = array(0 => array(0 => 'text',
        1 => 'Composition',
        2 => '1text1',
        3 => 'Test saf af saf'), 1 => array(0 => 'image',
        1 => 'c://xampp/htdocs/clickcue/application/app/webroot/files/ae_templates/rendered_templates/192/710/',
        2 => 'i1.jpg',
        3 => 'Chrysanthemum - Copy - Copy.jpg'));

foreach ($textAttributes as $textAttribute) {
    if ($textAttribute[0] == 'text') {
        echo end($textAttribute) . '<br/>';
    } else if ($textAttribute[0] == 'image') {
        echo $textAttribute[2] . '<br/>';
    }
}
```